# Bin folder message

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, bin

In a web server, when I delete the DLL files in the bin folder, the web page gives error.

How can I show `message.html` if there is no file in the bin folder?

Comment: No, you can't "catch" such error as it's not run-time or custom error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET has a feature which checks for the existence of a file called [app_offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) in the root of your site.

If this file is present, the HTML page will be served for every request to the application. This sounds like what you're looking for.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you can put an `app_offline.htm` file in your site root, then modify any files/assemblies as you need to. Then, remove `app_offline.htm` when you're done.